# SQL's `case when ...` code conversion using data.table package in R

Tags: sql, r, data.table

I am attempting to convert SQL code to R code. However, the data is around 35 million records with 200 columns each. So the best choice I could find is data.table package.

Here is the problem. 
In the SQL code I am able to perform an operation such as this,

```
select order_date,sum(case when item in ("D","C","B") then col4 end)as col1
sum(case when item not in ("Z","X","Y") then col4 end) as col2 
from datatable 
where col3 <25
group by order_date;
```

What the above query allows me to group by each date. I am unable to duplicate it in data.table. My attempts are as follows.

```
grp1<- c("D","C","B")
grp2<- c("Z","X","Y")
d1 <- dat[item %in% grp1,.(col1 = sum(col4,na.rm = TRUE),by = Order_Date]
d2 <- dat[item %in% grp2,.(col2 = sum(col4,na.rm = TRUE),by = Order_Date]
d3 <- data.table(d1,d2)
```

Now, since it `subsets` initially my grouping is different in both `d1` and `d2`

Comment: I know this is not your question, but are you aware that there are R packages that are able to run sql code (dplyr and others)?

Comment: I dont understand when you say ,not my question? I wish to implement all that using data.table package.

Comment: I'm interesting in timing of SQL and R solutions on your data (35Mx200), could you check and post it?

Comment: @jangorecki, sure I will post it back here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
DT[col3 < 25,
   .(col1 = sum(col4[item %in% c("D","C","B")]),
     col2 = sum(col4[!item %in% c("Z","X","Y")])),
   by = .(order_date)]
```

Comment: And now there is ```fcase()```although I'm not sure if it is great for this question. But for simple ```CASE WHEN``` conversions, users should look at ```data.table::fcase()```

Answer (score 0):

```
>     d <- "
+     order_date,item,col4,col3
+     2000-01-01,D,1,10
+     2000-01-01,C,1,10
+     2000-01-01,M,1,10
+     2000-01-01,N,1,50
+     2000-01-01,Z,1,10
+     2000-01-01,X,1,10
+     2001-01-02,Z,1,0
+     2001-01-02,X,1,50"
>
>     df = read.csv(textConnection(d))
>
>     # data.frame + plyr approach
>
>     require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
>     ddply(
+       df[df$col3<25,],
+       .(order_date),
+       summarize,
+       col1=sum(item %in% c("D","C","B") & col4),
+       col2=sum(!item %in% c("Z","X","Y") & col4)
+     )
      order_date col1 col2
1     2000-01-01    2    3
2     2001-01-02    0    0
>
>     # data.table approach, thanks to jangorecki
>
>     require(data.table)
Loading required package: data.table
>     dt = data.table(df)
>
>     dt[col3 < 25,
+        .(col1 = sum(col4[item %in% c("D","C","B")]),
+          col2 = sum(col4[!item %in% c("Z","X","Y")])),
+        by = .(order_date)]
       order_date col1 col2
1:     2000-01-01    2    3
2:     2001-01-02    0    0
>
```